# Better aproach for sorting numerical and text string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with column names inside `<th>` and only numbers inside `<td>`.
When I click on the `<th>` the sorting algoritm sorts values asc or desc.

```
.sortElements(function (a, b) {
    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
          inverse ? -1 : 1
          : inverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This sorts the text but there is the eternal `string vs number` problem. This sorts as string so 10 is smaller than 2 so I did this

```
.sortElements(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt($.text([a]),10) > parseInt($.text([b]),10) ?
          inverse ? -1 : 1
          : inverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This is sorting in the correct way (correct for my needs) if you have only numbers and 10 is bigger than 2.
Now I ask you... Is there a better way to do this?

What about if you have also letters inside `<td>`? What must be done? This is for someone who needs this to work correctly no matter what is inside `<td>`...?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't make us all wander in here to see what you're on about. See [ask].

Comment: Better? What do you want to improve?

Comment: `const direction = inverse ? -1 : 1; return +$.text([a]) > +$.text([b]) ? direction : -direction;` The negatives might be switched, but the same basic idea.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Correctly sorted is when 10 is bigger than 2 and sorted as such no matter if is text string or numerical

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Number() constructor for better readability

```
.sortElements(function (a, b) {
    return Number($.text([a])) > Number($.text([b])) ?
          inverse ? -1 : 1
          : inverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```